# How to prevent SonarQube not check specific vulnerability

Tags: sonarqube

I have some code that want to SonarQube not check this vulnerability while every deployment.
Any method for add rule for not check X type vulnerability with some error text ?

Answer (score 0):

I found an answer and want to inform for who need answer

- https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/24734/how-to-deactivate-a-rule-in-sonarqube

Need to copy existing SonarQube built-in profile and deactivate/add new rule in new profile,
after that go to project settings and change Quality Profile.